# JQuery - Click Submit Button Get Form Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, dom

I have the following function and all i am trying to do is get the value out of the form field.

```
$( ".searchbutton" ).click(function() {
    var tc = $(this).closest("form input[name='searchbox']").val();
    alert(tc);      
    return false;
});
```

The alert keeps telling me "Undefined".  I have treid closest, parent, parents, find, etc.  I don't know what im doing wrong.  Im clicking the submit button and all i want in return is the value in the search box.  Please help.

html

```
<form action="/index.php" method="get" class="qsearch" >
<input type="text" id="fsearch" name="searchbox" >
<input class="searchbutton" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: var tc = $('#fsearch').val();  since you already have id, why complicate?

Comment: Not sure if there is an id why are you not using `$('#fsearch').val();`?

Comment: @PratipGhosh, lol, at the same time (almost). :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
$( ".searchbutton" ).click(function() {
    var tc = $(this).closest("form").find("input[name='searchbox']").val();
    alert(tc);      
    return false;
});
```

**Update**
Yep, it work with your HTML - see here http://jsfiddle.net/qa6z3n1b/

As alternative - you must use

```
$( ".searchbutton" ).click(function() {
    var tc = $(this).siblings("input[name='searchbox']").val();
    alert(tc);      
    return false;
});
```

in your case. http://jsfiddle.net/qa6z3n1b/1/

Comment: @user982853, update. And small advice - do not use `alert()`, use `console.log()`

Answer (score 3):

Try easiest way:

```
<script>
$( ".searchbutton" ).click(function() {
var tc = $('#fsearch').val();
alert(tc);      
return false;
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just using `$('input[name="searchbox"]')` selector:

```
$( ".searchbutton" ).click(function() {
    var tc = $('input[name="searchbox"]').val();
    alert(tc);      
    return false;
});
```